# Why does my Python multiprocessing solution not only show diminishing returns but become slower with increased process count?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm working on my capstone project where I'm processing large tissue sample images into smaller tiles for multiple instance learning. Processing each image takes a non-insignificant amount of time so I have been working with multiprocessing to speed up the job. In my experiments, I began to find that increasing the number of processes only decreased the runtime up to a certain extent. I have access to my school's dual 64 core AMD Epyc 7H12 with 512GB ram. In my naivety, I thought that this would allow me to power through these images very quickly. On the contrary, I found the quickest runtimes happened using only 20 processes.

My program splits up the image into N sections, from which it then creates N processes to split each into the 255x256 png tiles before saving them into a specified directory.

Below I have a spreadsheet and plot of the runtimes on a single image with varied process counts.

Why does the runtime increase so drastically? Is it the act of saving the tiles that forms a bottleneck?

[image: Multiprocess Runtimes]

I was expecting the runtimes to decrease as I increased the number of processes, splitting the images into smaller and smaller pieces. Instead the runtimes increased.

Here is some of the code in question:

Save routine:

```
def save_loop(row1, col1, directory, tiles, imagename, levelnum):
    for row in row1:
        for col in col1:
            tile_name = os.path.join(directory, imagename + '_%d_%d' % (col, row))
            temp_tile_np = np.array(tiles.get_tile(levelnum, (col, row)).convert('RGB'))
            if (temp_tile_np.mean() < 150) and temp_tile_np.std() > 15:
                Image.fromarray(temp_tile_np).save(tile_name + ".png")
            del temp_tile_np
            gc.collect()
```

Saving each tile to local directory:

```
  cols, rows = tiles.level_tiles[level_num]

  t_rows = tuple(split(range(rows), process_count))
  t_cols = tuple(split(range(cols), process_count))
  processes = []
  proce = 0
  
  tic = time.time()

  for i in range(process_count):
    for j in range(process_count):
      proce += 1
      p = Process(target=save_loop, args=(t_rows[i], t_cols[j], tile_dir, tiles,manifest.filename[k][:-4], level_num, ))
      p.start()
      processes.append(p)
  gc.collect()
  for p in processes:
    p.join()
  print(f'Time to process image is {time.time() - tic} seconds')
```

Comment: Starting a process, giving it its data, and retrieving the result has a certain overhead. It's hard to say without seeing any code, but it's possible that's the cause; past twenty processes, the overhead for spinning each one up is no longer offset by the time gained by parallel processing. Can you share any of the code, or describe in more detail how much data you're working with?

Comment: If a lot of the work is disk I/O, then yeah, very easily you will run into a situation where too many processes each trying to write to disk will cause it to slow down. It's hard to say, we can really only speculate without way more details

Comment: Can you elaborate on exactly what each process is doing?

Comment: I added the code to the main post

Comment: Since we don't have access to the full code, it's hard to say with certainty. However, I/O is a likely bottleneck and given that 30 cores running seem to take about half as long each as 60 running each, some hard ceiling like I/O bandwidth is worth checking. One way you could do that is by drastically changing I/O, for example set up a RAM disk and write to that - now your code will be writing to memory and the bottleneck will shift back to code (for a bit at least), of course space will be very limited.

Comment: Have you looked at the actual I/O bandwidth required? That is, how much data is your script trying to write per unit of time on average? A simple test script would tell you how much you ought to be able to write consistently (keep in mind that initially, caching will make your storage seem faster than the speed it will be able to sustain once caches are saturated).

Comment: Are you calling `process_count` the number of processes?  If so, that's really creating `process_count ** 2` processes, which will quickly swamp your system.

Comment: @AnonCoward you are absolutely right. I feel very ridiculous not realizing that that's what I was doing. While I'm sure I/O is a factor, I'm using way to many processors and creating a backlog of work. 20² is 400...

Comment: Might be worth using `Pool` from multiprocessing, it provides nice primitives (e.g. `map`) that seem like they could simplify your code